# Can't get Wordpress form submission to work

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins, submission

I know this question has been asked repeatedly, but none of the solutions that I have found are working for me. I have a simple wordpress plugin that outputs the form html via the shortcode on the page. When I fill in the form, it is not hitting the form action callback and I can not figure out why. Here is my code:

```html
<?php
/*
 Plugin Name: Form Submit Test
 Plugin URI: http://10.0.2.15/wp-content/plugins/form-submit-test
 Description: Testing to get these forms to submit
 Version: 1.0.0
 Author: Randy Young
 Author URI: http://example.com
 License: GPLv2 or later
*/


// security check
defined('ABSPATH') or  die('Illegal Access');
define( 'FormSubmitTest_VERSION', '1.0.0' );

class FormSubmitTest
{


    function fst_shortcode() {
        return $this->html_form_code();
    }

    private function html_form_code() {
        error_log('html_form_code()');
        $html = '';
        $html .= '<form action="' . esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php')) . '" method="post">'; //
        $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="action" value="fst_action_hook"';
        $html .= '<p>';
        $html .= 'Your Name (required) <br />';
        $html .= '<input type="text" name="cf-name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-name"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-name"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
        $html .= '</p>';
        $html .= '<p>';
        $html .= 'Your Email (required) <br />';
        $html .= '<input type="email" name="cf-email" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-email"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-email"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
        $html .= '</p>';
        $html .= '<p>';
        $html .= 'Subject (required) <br />';
        $html .= '<input type="text" name="cf-subject" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-subject"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-subject"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
        $html .= '</p>';
        $html .= '<p>';
        $html .= 'Your Message (required) <br />';
        $html .= '<textarea rows="10" cols="35" name="cf-message">' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-message"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-message"] ) : '' ) . '</textarea>';
        $html .= '</p>';
        $html .= '<p><input type="submit" name="cf-submitted" value="Send"/></p>';
        $html .= '</form>';

        return $html;
    }
}


// instantiate the FormSubmitTest class
if( class_exists('FormSubmitTest')) {
    $formSubmitTest = new FormSubmitTest();
}

add_action( 'wp_post_nopriv_fst_action_hook', 'fst_action_function' ); // need this to serve non logged in users
add_action( 'wp_post_fst_action_hook', 'fst_action_function' );
// THE FUNCTION
function fst_action_function() {

    error_log('fst_action_function()');
    
    wp_redirect(admin_url('admin.php?page=10.0.2.15/index.php/ringwood2/'));
    exit;
}

// create a shortcode to add to the page
add_shortcode('form_submit_test', array( $formSubmitTest, 'fst_shortcode'));

?>
```

I see the  error_log('html_form_code()'); result in the debug.log, but I do not see error_log('fst_action_function()'); result from the callback. I also end up on the wp-admin/admin-post.php page.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to submit the form via AJAX, and have the wrong action. For AJAX, it should be wp_ajax, not wp_post.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax__nopriv_fst_action_hook', 'fst_action_function' ); // need this to serve non logged in users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_fst_action_hook', 'fst_action_function' );
```

You can find more information here: [wp_ajax_{action}_](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)). This would essentially allow you to submit the form via AJAX, but, you cannot redirect in the way you are attempting. With AJAX, you would typically return a response, and then do something with that response in Javascript, such as display a message (or redirect).

If you prefer to simply post the form without AJAX, you should instead consider using the [init](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) action. Then you can listen for the form submission. Something like,

```
add_action( 'init', 'listen_for_form_submissions' );

function listen_for_form_submissions() {
    if( isset( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] === 'fst_action_hook' ) {
        error_log('fst_action_function()');

        wp_redirect(admin_url('admin.php?page=10.0.2.15/index.php/ringwood2/'));
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chris. I am confused though. What makes you believe that my intent was to use ajax? I am attempting to use the wp_post_{action} methodology. What am I doing wrong? Would I be better off using ajax?

Comment: I do not believe wp_post_{action} is a valid hook. I’m not finding anything in the WP docs

Comment: And the nopriv_ flag is a documented element of wp_ajax

Comment: Thanks Chris. according to the examples that I  have seen,  the hook in your example would be wp_post_nopriv_listen_for_form_submissions (for non logged in users) and wp_post_listen_for_form_submissions for logged in users. At any rate, I took your suggestion to use the 'init' action. It works great. Thank you so much.